# Делегирование: не удается передать данные из одного контроллера в другой. SWIFT

Tags: swift, делегаты

Здравствуйте мне нужно перенести структуру из одного контроллера в другой, при помощи делегирования, но что то не получается.

У меня есть 2 вью контроллера: 1-таблица, которую я подписал на делегат, с функцией принять структуру:

```
protocol AddItemDelegate {
func addItemToArrey(_ addExpences: AddExpences, didAddItem item : Item )
}
class ViewControllerApp: UIViewController, AddItemDelegate {
let addExpencesVC = AddExpences()
var items = [Item]()
let cellId = "My cell"
```

Реализовываю функцию протокола делегирования, чтобы добавить экземпляр структуры в массив

```
func addItemToArrey(_ addExpences: AddExpences, didAddItem item: Item) {
    items.append(item)
    tableViewApp.reloadData()
    print("------ \(items)")
}
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewApp: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addExpencesVC.delegate = self   
}
@IBAction func AddButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddingExpenceVC")
    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
} }
```

Настраиваю таблицу

```
extension ViewControllerApp: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}
```

Передаю в ячейку таблицы данные из экземпляра структуры

```
    let item = items [indexPath.row]
    cell.ExpenceLabelName.text = item.name
    let preQuantity = item.quantity
    let quantity = String(preQuantity)
    cell.ExpenceLabeQuantity.text = quantity
    cell.ExpenceImage.image = UIImage(named: "image-3")
    return cell
}
```

}

И 2 всплывающее окно с формой для заполнения данных структуры с кнопкой "Сохранить".

```
class AddExpences: UIViewController {
```

Указываю делегат класса

```
var delegate: AddItemDelegate?
var pickture: UIImage?

@IBAction func saveCklicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
```

/// Через аутлеты передаю информацию в структуру

```
    let name = expenceNameTextField.text ?? " "
    
    let preQuantity = expenceQuantityTextField.text ?? " "
    let quantity = Int(preQuantity)!
    
    let prePrice = expencePriceTextField.text ?? " "
    let price = Int(prePrice)!
    
    let defaultImg = UIImage(named: "image-3")
    var image: UIImage{
        if pickture != nil {
            return pickture!
        } else {
            return defaultImg!
        }
    }
```

/// Создаю новый экземпляр структуры

```
    let newItem = Item(name: name, quantity: quantity, price: price, image: image)
      print("//////\(newItem)")
```

/// Передаю экземпляр делегату

```
    delegate?.addItemToArrey(self, didAddItem: newItem)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

}

На этом этапе экземпляр создается и через команду принт отображается в консоли, но вот в первый вью контроллер этот экземпляр не доходит и не отображается в нем, подскажите что я упустил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас экземпляр AddingExpenceVC создается вот здесь:

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddingExpenceVC") as? AddingExpenceVC
```

Поэтому делегата нужно указать тоже здесь:

```
vc?.delegate = self
```

И тогда это не нужно:

```
let addExpencesVC = AddExpences()
addExpencesVC.delegate = self
```

Comment: Или я не правильно понял, или не получается:
Эта константа находится внутри функции кнопки для смены контроллера и доступа извне к ней нету.

`let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddingExpenceVC")`

Если я внутри этой же функции дописываю 

`vc.delegate = self `

То получаю ошибку от компилятора "Value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'delegate'"
Если эту же строчку забиваю сразу во вью дидактиков лоад, то компилятор, что не может найти такую константу в зоне своей видимости

Comment: Может в таком случае нужно как то вынести строчку `let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddingExpenceVC")`
Вынести за границы видимости функции кнопки? Я пока не понимаю как, если просто выношу из скобок функции, то получаю ошибку "Cannot use instance member 'storyboard' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Comment: Чтобы Xcode увидел delegate у AddingExpenceVC, вам нужно скастовать vc до AddingExpenceVC, т.е. написать let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddingExpenceVC") as? AddingExpenceVC, а затем vc?.delegate = self. Добавил в ответ.

Comment: Да, все получилось, я сперва не заметил привидения vc к AddingExpenceVC, сейчас все заработало! Огромное спасибо!)

Comment: Пожалуйста, хорошо, что получилось)